# What is the most efficient Organic Photovoltaic solar cell?

Tags: renewable-energy, solar-cells

Preferably one that is researched in a paper, not necessarily in production.

I have found various claims of OPVs with an efficiency of 10%, 8% and 7.3%, the only one I can substantiate is referenced in a paper in Advanced Materials (Volume 22, Issue 34 pp 3839–3856) to Solarmer but the web reference there leads to a news page where the news have been removed.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers Not much that's in a paper, but lots of 'claims'

Comment: This chart [Best Research-Cell Efficiencies](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c9/PVeff%28rev111205%29.jpg) may be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Developments as of summer 2014

The hottest kid on the organic-PV block is [perovskites](http://www.technologyreview.com/news/517811/a-material-that-could-make-solar-power-dirt-cheap/): in February 2012, Hardin, Snaith & McGehee published [an article in Nature Photonics announcing "The renaissance of dye-sensitized solar cells"](http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nphoton.2012.22). The inventors of one implementation, [Oxford Photovoltaics Ltd (a spinoff of the University of Oxford)](http://www.oxfordpv.com/oxford-pv-news/oxford-pv-reveals-breakthrough-in-efficiency-of-new-class-of-solar-cell) described their new technology in [Science, in November 2012](http://dx.doi.org/10.1126/science.1228604), and have a patent application pending for their [dye-sensitized solar cell](http://www.google.com/patents/WO2013030553A1). For more, see [recent papers by Henry J. Snaith's team](http://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?as_ylo=2013&q=author:%22hj%20snaith%22&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5). Folk have got excited because of the rapid increases in efficiency since 2009, combined with the very low cost and abundance of the raw material: as of summer 2014, the record was $17.9\pm0.8\%$, held by the Korea Research Institute of Chemical Technology

[image]
[<sub>(image source)</sub>](http://www2.physics.ox.ac.uk/research/photovoltaic-and-optoelectronic-device-group)

---

### Confirmed organic PV records under standard test conditions

Progress in Photovoltaics: Research and Applications publishes a biannual review of PV efficiency records, under the name [Solar cell efficiency tables](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/advanced/search/results/reentry?scope=allContent&dateRange=allDates&inTheLastList=6&startYear=&endYear=&queryStringEntered=false&searchRowCriteria[0].queryString=Solar+cell+efficiency+tables&searchRowCriteria[0].fieldName=document-title&searchRowCriteria[0].booleanConnector=and&searchRowCriteria[1].fieldName=all-fields&searchRowCriteria[1].booleanConnector=and&searchRowCriteria[2].fieldName=all-fields&searchRowCriteria[2].booleanConnector=and&start=1&resultsPerPage=20&ordering=date). The [2014 June review](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/pip.2525) gave a record efficiency under standard test conditions for an organic PV **cell** of $10.7\pm0.3\%$. For an organic PV **mini-module**, the record is $9.1\pm0.3\%$. (NB The higher perovskite efficiencies discussed above had not passed audited standard tests in time for the latest biannual review)

Cells have higher efficiencies than sub-modules, which tend to have higher efficiencies than modules. A (sub- or mini-)module is made up of several cells , and power is aggregated from all of the cells. The most efficient cell in a (sub-/mini-)module will, by definition, have an efficiency equal to or higher than all other cells in that (sub-/mini-)module; and not all the module surface area is covered in cells; therefore record cell efficiency will always be higher than (sub-mini/)module efficiency.

Here's the recent history of organic PV cell record efficiencies (%, standard test conditions):

2012-10 $10.7\pm0.3$

2011-10 $10.0\pm0.3$

2010-11 $8.3\pm0.3$

2006-12 $~5.15\pm0.3$

2006-03 $~3.0\pm0.1$

---

### Overall PV record

The record efficiency for any PV cell is $44.4\pm2.6\%$, for a InGaP/GaAs/InGaAs inverted metamorphic cell (2013-04), measured at 302 suns, AM 1.5, cell temp $25^{\circ}C$ .

Comment: Could you specify the difference here between cell and sub-module?