# Photovoltaic IV data

Tags: optics, resource-recommendations, renewable-energy, solar-cells

I am looking for any available measured solar-cell datasets (Voltage/Current) especially for organic photovoltaic cells for the testing of a software unfortunately I am unable to get the measured values. Please mention if anyone knows about any on-line available data set?

Comment: Seeing as solar cells can be manufactured in any number of sizes or wiring configurations, I imagine the voltage/current outputs of commercial solar cell arrays will cover an enormous range of values. Because of this, could you just make up some reasonable numbers? What is the software trying to do?

Comment: I want to test the characterization part of the software. Lets say one will input the measured voltage and current values for a cell and the output will be the IV curve with calculated Fill-Factor, efficiency, Open ckt voltage, Short ckt current, current and voltage at maximum power etc.

Comment: Everything you're trying to calculate is very straightforward math. For example, for maximum power, you multiply I and V at each point and look for the maximum. For open-circuit voltage, you look at where the IV curve crosses I=0. So you're actually just trying to check whether or not you made a dumb programming error. Made-up data is perfectly adequate for this purpose.

Comment: here is another sourse of i v data please read the following paper it contains usefull data : https://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijp/2015/963562/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it just looks for plain data, rather than *actual* physics. If the data exists, it should be just a quick google search away.

Answer (score 1):

You'll usually find these data in the Supplementary Information of relevant papers. If you find a paper where they've made such measurements, but don't give them in supplementary information, you can email the contact author, with a couple of paragraphs explaining what data you're after, and what use you'll put it to.

For example, [here's the Supplementary Information](http://www.rsc.org/suppdata/ee/c3/c3ee43707h/c3ee43707h.pdf) with observations, for the paper [Sub-150 °C processed meso-superstructured perovskite solar cells with enhanced efficiency](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/C3EE43707H) by Konrad Wojciechowski, Michael Saliba, Tomas Leijtens, Antonio Abate and Henry J. Snaith. Henry Snaith is one of the world's leading researchers in perovskite PV, which looks like one of the more promising areas of organic/inorganic hybrid PV research, because of the potential for very low-cost manufacture (and in earthbound, rather than space, PV, it's all about cost - I largely ignore hype about [efficiency](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/19343/4066)). You could take a look down [his list of publications](https://www2.physics.ox.ac.uk/contacts/people/snaith/publications), to find journals that might have the data you're after.

Answer (score -1):

you can use the following data for a ordinary solar cell unfortunatelly not organic one:

```
V(V)    I(mA)   P(mW)
0.006   12.526  0.07516
0.055   12.505  0.68778
0.113   12.523  1.4151
0.169   12.488  2.11047
0.228   12.476  2.84453
0.285   12.46   3.5511
0.343   12.505  4.28922
0.397   12.466  4.949
0.455   12.441  5.66066
0.513   12.423  6.373
0.574   12.415  7.12621
0.63    12.41   7.8183
0.689   12.401  8.54429
0.744   12.397  9.22337
0.804   12.327  9.91091
0.861   12.381  10.66004
0.92    12.353  11.36476
0.976   12.323  12.02725
1.035   12.254  12.68289
1.091   12.212  13.32329
1.15    12.261  14.10015
1.205   12.253  14.76487
1.265   12.251  15.49752
1.32    12.26   16.1832
1.377   12.246  16.86274
1.435   12.265  17.60028
1.496   12.283  18.37537
1.553   12.315  19.12519
1.608   12.26   19.71408
1.665   12.249  20.39459
1.722   12.265  21.12033
1.784   12.285  21.91644
1.838   12.27   22.55226
1.899   12.241  23.24566
1.954   12.224  23.8857
2.014   12.223  24.61712
2.071   12.199  25.26413
2.13    12.195  25.97535
2.186   12.145  26.54897
2.245   12.112  27.19144
2.302   12.059  27.75982
2.36    11.91   28.1076
2.417   11.756  28.41425
2.475   11.572  28.6407
2.532   11.294  28.59641
2.587   10.988  28.42596
2.648   10.599  28.06615
2.702   10.108  27.31182
2.764   9.435   26.07834
2.82    8.705   24.5481
2.879   7.714   22.20861
2.935   6.539   19.19197
2.991   5.142   15.37972
3.048   3.485   10.62228
3.109   1.443   4.48629
3.146   0   0
```

Comment: Source?${}{}{}$